# EC2 Plugin using Spot Instances fails - Creates zombies, Instable

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins ver. 2.150.3 
Ubuntu 18.04 Host 
Amazon EC2 plugin 1.42

Hey.

The plugin works perfectly without Spot instances!

I've tried to use the `Amazon EC2 plugin` with Spot Instances ( m5d.12xlarge ).

The AMI image was configured correctly as of https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin steps.

My jobs needs one Instance based on Label ( linux ).

The Instance Count Limit is set to 4/this instance and 4/Global.

The problem starts to happen when Jenkins is trying to create a Spot Instance to serve my builds queue.

In AWS i get around 7-8 Spot Instances created at an interval of 3~30 seconds when i only need one ...

Jenkins only sees only one Agent online, doesn't even see the others as offline ...

Am i missing something? Did I do something wrong ?

Thanks!